# Objective-C - Keeping variables in .h or .m - any difference?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In .h file -

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    @someAccessibilityModifier int a; // someAccessibilityModifier = @public, @private
}
```

or in .m file -

```
@implementation MyClass {
    @someAccessibilityModifier int a; // someAccessibilityModifier = @public, @private
}
```

Any difference in above two (since both ways, `a` 's accessibility and behavior will be same)?

Answer (score 5):

In the former, `a` *is* accessible outside the class. You have to specify `@private` if you don't want that to be true.

In any case, unless you explicitly want your ivar to be visible outside the class (and you almost certainly don't), you should use the latter form (specifying in the `@implementation`). Ivars are generally considered to be implementation details, and as such should not be in the header.

The only exception to this is if you're writing 32-bit OS X code, because that still uses the fragile ABI which requires all ivars to be declared in the `@interface`.

Comment: @onlinenaman: Accessibility modifiers don't mean anything in `@implementation` because the variable isn't even visible to other classes.

Comment: @onlinenaman: Also, the second and third paragraphs of my answer don't depend on accessibility modifiers.

Comment: So, any difference between declaring with @private in .h and declaring in .m without any accessibility modifier?

Comment: Having the ivars in the .h file means that if you need to change the implementation, all classes that include the .h will be recompiled. If you put them in the .m, dependent classes don't recompile and your are also doing a better job of hiding the implementation details.

Comment: The header file should only contain the public interface to the class, and nothing more. Ivars should not be placed into the header unless they're considered part of the public interface (and they really shouldn't be), with 32-bit OS X being the only exception.